# What would you call a course provided by a company to give extra qualifications to its employees?

Tags: terminology

I was thinking something like *integrative/supplementary/auxiliary/subsidiary courses/classes/lessons/training*. I'm not sure which one would be best.

What I mean is a course that would give an employee extra knowledge in order to step up the career ladder and gain new responsabilities.

thanks

Comment: Just a minor point.  In English we always say "what would you call ..." rather than "how would you call ...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call it "**career development training**" or "**skills development training**".  The term "course" or "programme" could also be used instead of "training".

From [mbaskool.com](https://www.mbaskool.com/business-concepts/human-resources-hr-terms/1779-career-development.html)

> **Career development** is the series of activities or the on-going/lifelong process of developing one’s career. Career development usually refers to managing one’s career in an intra-organizational or inter-organizational scenario. It involves training on new skills, moving to higher job responsibilities, making a career change within the same organization, moving to a different organization or starting one’s own business.

From [td.org](https://www.td.org/Publications/Blogs/Career-Development-Blog/2014/10/How-Career-Development-Programs-Support-Employee-Retention):

> Your company can develop its own unique **career development programs** to increase employee retention—and hopefully increase productivity and profits

From [learn.org](https://learn.org/articles/What_is_Career_Development_Training.html):

> Many employers include **career development training** in their benefits packages, giving employees the opportunity to further their professional education and advance their skills.

From [Abundant Sun](http://www.abundantsun.com/services/personal-skills-development-training/):

> we have carefully developed a suite of **personal skills development programmes** to help employers assist their employees to overcome career barriers and reach more senior levels in their respective organisations.

Answer (score 5):

[Refresher course](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/refresher-course) may fit your description:

> A refresher course is a training course in which people improve their knowledge or skills and learn about new developments that are related to the job that they do.

(Collins)

Career advancements courses  can be referred to as:

***Professional development courses:***

> development courses give education opportunities to indivduals seeking advancement in their career.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this term, and I think it fits well. Still, some definitions see it simply as an "updating" course. What I meant was a course that would teach you something new in order to make an employee step up the career ladder with new responsability (I'm going to edit my post now)